# Building data to pass to jquery/ajax dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have the following **web method** that I wish to call through jquery-ajax.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int saveDataToServer(string cntName, string cntEmail, string cntMsg)
{
     // Implementation
}
```

This is my **jquery ajax calling method**...

```
    function makeAjaxCall(arrOfObjName, arrOfObjValues, urlToCall) {
        debugger;
        var tempData;
        // Check if objNames's length is same as objValues's length.
        if (arrOfObjName.length != arrOfObjValues.length) {
            return null;
        }
        var dataString = "";
        // Building data object, we know the two arrays have same length!
        for (var intIndex = 0; intIndex < arrOfObjName.length; ++intIndex) {
            if (intIndex == arrOfObjName.length - 1) {
                dataString += arrOfObjName[intIndex] + ":" + arrOfObjValues[intIndex];
                continue;
            }
            dataString += arrOfObjName[intIndex] + ":" + arrOfObjValues[intIndex] + ",";
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: urlToCall,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify("{" + dataString + "}"),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                tempData = data;
            },
            error: function (data) {
                tempData = null;
            }
        });
        return tempData;
    }
```

Before calling the method, I'm **passing it arrays**,

```
 var arrOfObjects = new Array("cntName", "cntEmail", "cntMsg");
 var arrOfObjectVals = new Array($(cntName).val(),$(cntEmail).val(),$(cntMsg).val());
```

But when the actual call happens, I get the **following error in Fiddler**.

```
{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

I assume that the method is having problems converting the "string type data" to a dictionary. But why so in the first place? Can I not build the data that I wish to pass to the web-method dynamically ?

**Updated as requested** :

```
>> JSON.stringify("{" + dataString + "}")

""{cntName:asdasdasd,cntEmail:abijeet.p@osmosys.asia,cntMsg:saveDataToServersaveDataToServersaveDataToServersaveDataToServersaveDataToServersaveDataToServersaveDataToServer}""
```

Comment: You can, what you're passing probably just isn't in the format .net expects. Could you grab the output of JSON.stringify("{" + dataString + "}") and add to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building a string with `dataString`, you should be building an object then converting that object to json. Something like

```
    var dataString = {};
    // Building data object, we know the two arrays have same length!
    for (var intIndex = 0; intIndex < arrOfObjName.length; ++intIndex) {
        dataString[arrOfObjName[intIndex]] = arrOfObjValues[intIndex];
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToCall,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify( dataString ),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            tempData = data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            tempData = null;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll accept this as an answer as soon as I can. Any other recommendations you might have?

Comment: Try reading this site a little bit... I think what you're doing is overkill. You don't need to send JSON strings, just send the object and let ASP.Net deserialize it. http://encosia.com/jquery-for-the-asp-net-developer/  (a collection of blogs about JQuery and ASP.Net)

Comment: Here's the specific article that helped me figure this out: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and add this as an answer: you're doing too much work yourself, let the framework do all that stuff!

http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Your AJAX call needs to just be this... no need to make a JSON string yourself!

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToCall,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: arrOfOBJECTS, //looky here! 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            tempData = data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            tempData = null;
        }
    });
```

And then on your back-end service, change the signature to something like this...

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static int saveDataToServer(string[] myArray)
{
     // Implementation
}
```

Only, use some struct or object that matches your JSON object. Don't do this work yourself. It did take me a couple days to get this figured out, but when you do, it's beauty.